# gradle sync taking too much time android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have imported a Android Studio 2.1 project to Android Studio 2.2.3. But the gradle sync is taking too much time. Current Gradle version is 2.14.1 Even I have used another gradle(2.10) No error shown on the event log. Have no idea where I am stuck. Don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: Need more detail. Please show us the `build.gradle`

Comment: What do you consider "too much time"? One of our larger projects takes a minute or two sometimes, yes. Nothing I'd worry about. So, how long is "too long"?

Comment: A simple two-activity project is taking around 8 minutes..